# Best Practice to switch CCLayer, like CCDirector switches CCScene

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

Could someone please advise or point me to links on how to switch CCLayer just like

```
[ [CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene: [SomeCustomScene scene] ];
```

I am planning on using CCLayers for managing Menu System and Levels in my game projects, instead of using CCScenes. I am planning on creating a 'SharedLayer' (Singleton) just like sharedDirector to swap levels and menus.

E.g.: `[ [MySharedLayer sharedLayer] replaceLayer: [MyCustomLayer node] ];`

Are there any better approaches. Please advise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @sg7 for your feedback. I feel comfortable that creating a Singleton CCLayer is a good approach of swapping Layers, just like CCDirector replaces Scenes, since in my projects, I intend to have just one Scene. If I was trying to keep a stack of Layers for fast swapping I would have definitely taken the CCLayerMultiplex route.

I took a different route in my case. I made a Singleton of my SceneMgr class (inherited from CCScene) with a CCLayer property(current) and a switchLayer method.

```
//I can now switch layers like this...
//There is a static SceneMgr being used, so only one instance exists
[ [SceneMgr scene].current switchLayer: myNewLayer withAction: fadeIn];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use: **CCLayerMultiplex**

*CCLayerMultiplex* is a CCLayer with the ability to multiplex it's children.

Features:

- It supports one or more children
- Only one children will be active a time

Ref:

a)
http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/1.0.0/interface_c_c_layer_multiplex.html

b)
http://books.google.ca/books?id=9CQL8t6Eob0C&pg=PA104&lpg=PA104&dq=CCMultiplexLayer&source=bl&ots=AgsaLtHNyX&sig=vpYxnf4jUeuQHauxmmIuuv6MJzU&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Tn_WUI3jBsmCqgHpo4DYCw&ved=0CE0Q6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=CCMultiplexLayer&f=false

The method:

```
  - (void) switchTo:(unsigned int) n;
```

will allow you to switch between layers.

Comment: Appreciate your feedback. I am aware of 'CCLayerMultiplex' and I am not trying to keep an array of layers, it will bloat memory. Secondly, from doing a number of readings CCLayerMultiplex does not support transitions. I am trying to load one CCLayer at a time. Goal is layers come and go as needed, not stored in a collection and popped off after usage.

Comment: Your approach is fine! I am not aware of anything better. I have a collection of layers that I switch as needed. I keep them in memory for fast swap from layer to layer.
I can imagine that you can have just one scene (can be think of as a singleton) which would create and dispose layers as needed. In my case a scene does what your singleton could do. My main scene keeps track of the layers and keeps common resources available.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. You are correct, I have just one CCScene (SceneMgr), it will keep track of global data in HUD (achievements, score, health, etc) and a UI layer for controls. There will be another CCLayer pointer inside SceneMgr that will point to whatever the current layer maybe (Menu or Game Level). The Menu/Level will have its own set of gameplay, BG, sounds, etc encapsulated inside it. This way the SeneMgr is only responsible to provide TouchEvents to GameLevel and update HUD on updates from GameLevel